# Translations in reopen review queue about a "reason" are not used

Tags: bug, review, localization, reopen-dialog

If you don't select a reason in post reopen review queue you will get messages (depending on the popup level):

- You must select a reason before submitting.

> [image]

- You must select a community specific reason before submitting.

> [image]

All these sentences are [translated](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=before%20submitting) several builds ago, but for some reason still displayed in English on ruSO.

Related post on ruSO.meta: [Отсутствует перевод всплывающего сообщения в очереди голосов за переоткрытие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13123/176217)